# Difference variables in quotes (inside the command)

Tags: bash, variables, command, quotes, dereference

I am running my script in different environments and therefore I store the path and name of program I want to start in variable `$CreateSequenceDictionary`.

This program uses parameters `R=` and `O=` for this reason I put the whole command in quotations "". Without these, program is started without any paramaters.

And now my problem: instead of `$reference` I would like to pass content of this variable. I tried this:

```
"java -jar $CreateSequenceDictionary R=$reference O=output" >mlogfile
```

and many variations (such as `` "" eval \) with no success.

Please, how should I adjust my command so I could run program stored in variable with parameter stored in variable?

EDIT: If I should use command in terminal, it would look like this:

```
 java -jar /path/CreateSequenceDictionary.jar R=input O=output
```

However, I want to get name of the program from variable and also name of input file from variable.

Comment: So how does this work? You have a variable named `$reference` and you want to alias the very same variable with `R`? What's the point?

Comment: No, normally the command looks like this: java -jar /path/CreateSequenceDictionary.jar R=input O=output and I want to get program name from variable and also name of input file from variable (this input file is one of the parameters program CreateSequenceDictionary.jar needs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that without the surrounding quotes.

```
java -jar $CreateSequenceDictionary R=$reference O=output > mlogfile
```

Bash will expand the vars before running the command.

If you want to conditionally include the `R=` and `O=` options, you could try something like this:

```
CreateSequenceDictionary="your_Program"
r_option ="$reference"
o_option="output"

arguments=()
[[ "$r_option" ]] && arguments+=("$r_option")
[[ "$o_option" ]] && arguments+=("$o_option")

java -jar $CreateSequenceDictionary "${arguments[@]}" > mlogfile
```

This builds the additional arguments on-the-fly and skips those where the associated `*_option` variable is empty.

Comment: to protect against option values with whitespace, use an array: `arguments=(); [[ "$r_option" ]] && arguments+=("$r_option"); ...; java ... "${arguments[@]}" ...` -- note it's generally advised to avoid uppercase variable names so you don't accidentally override a system or environment variable.

Comment: I will try the way you add parameters. However, without the surrounding quotes, program is started without any parameters. I am quite sure about this as it yields to "ERROR: Option 'OUTPUT' is required."

Comment: @Perlnika How exactly are you running the statement? In fact, it should NOT work WITH the surrounding quotes since bash would treat the whole line as a command.

Comment: @ShawnChin this is part of my .sh script:  java -jar "$CreateSequenceDictionary REFERENCE=$reference OUTPUT=output" >mlogfile 2>>errlogfile and it yields to Unable to access jarfile /software/picard-1.80/CreateSequenceDictionary.jar REFERENCE= OUTPUT=output (content of $reference is lost)

Comment: @Perlnika That won't work. By adding those quotes you're treating the whole line (jar file and options) as a single argument to java. Leave out the surrounding quotes and do make sure `$reference` is actually defined (try `echo $reference` within your script).

Comment: You are right, I accidentaly did not assign any value to $reference. Accepting your answer, thanks.